# Why does my array return null or show an empty array, after appending values to it

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting values from a firebase real-time database. I want to store these values into an array and display them in a UITableView. Here is what is happening:

---

I have defined the Array before my viewDidLoad() function as the following:

```
var taskTitles: [Task] = []
```

---

In my `viewDidLoad()` function I am calling another function to generate the array:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Setting the Title for the nav bar
    title = "To Do List"

    configureNavigationItems()

    taskTitles = createArray() // creating the array of tasks in db
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    
    
}
```

---

In this function, I am passing information to my classes. Task and TaskCell. They are simply just handling the Title of the task.

```
    func createArray() -> [Task] {
        
        
        taskRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Tasks")
        
        //getting values from db, storing them in an array.
        refHandle = taskRef?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
            for taskSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                let nodeA = taskSnapshot as! DataSnapshot
                let keyA = nodeA.key
                let theTask = Task(title: String(keyA))
                self.taskTitles.append(theTask)
                print("In the FOR Loop --> ", self.taskTitles)
            }
            print("outside of FOR  Loop --> ", self.taskTitles)
        })
        print("outside of observe func --> ", taskTitles)
        
        return taskTitles
    
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to save my items into the array. I did some debugging to figure where things were going wrong. Hopefully, the picture below can clarify:[image]

---

### **Any idea what the issue is?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `taskRef?.observe` is asynchronous.  That is why you see "outside of observe func --> []" printed before the other lines.

What is happening is that your `createArray()` function calls `observe` and then returns `taskTitles` which is still empty.  Then your view finishes loading and shows (presumably) an empty table.  After this the `observe` function calls your closure with the snapshot and you update `taskTitles`, but at this point `tableView` is already on screen and empty and you would have to take further actions to reload it (like, for example, calling `reloadData()` on it).

It is perhaps also worth mentioning that you are modifying your property in that function, then returning it, and assigning it to itself.  This is perhaps redundant.

Comment: Such an easy fix. Thank you for not scolding me, lol.

Comment: It's an honest mistake.  Just keep in mind most of the time you have to pass a handler to something like this, it is probably asynchronous. :)